# Why $L^{-1}U^T=D$ in LU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

I learned that given a matrix $A$, we can apply LU decomposition to get $A=LU$, where $L$ is lower triangular and $U$ is upper triangular. Further, if $A$ is symmetric (or Hermitian for complex $A$), then we can apply Symmetric Doolittle Factorization to get $LU=LDL^T$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
 LU&=A\\
 &=A^T\\
 &=U^TL^T\\
 U&=L^{-1}U^TL^T\\
    &=DL^T &\rightarrow\text{why}\,L^{-1}U^T=D?\\
    LU&=LDL^T
\end{align*}
$$

But I do not understand why $L^{-1}U^T=D$, from what I understand, the inverse of a lower triangular is also a lower triangular, and the transpose of an upper triangular is lower triangular, so $L^{-1}U^T$ is the matrix multiplication of two lower triangular matrices, which will result in a lower triangular matrix, but I do not see how it is going to be a diagonal matrix. May someone help to explain it to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define $D := L^{-1} U^T$. Therefore, as you wrote,
$$
U = L^{-1} U^T L^T = D L^T \Rightarrow\\
U = D L^T \Rightarrow\\
U (L^{-1})^T = D \Rightarrow\\
D^T = L^{-1} U^T
$$
From the equation above one can conclude, that $D^T = D$. Given that $D$ is lower triangular and symmetric we derive, that $D$ is diagonal.